# Is there value in producing code so flexible that it will never need to be updated?

Tags: active-directory

I am currently involved in a debate with my coworkers surrounding how I should design an API that will be used by my department. Specifically, I am tasked with writing an API that will serve as a <strike>wrapper</strike> **facade** to access Active Directory information - tailored to my company's/department's needs. I am aware that open source <strike>wrappers</strike> **facades** already exist but that *is not* the crux of this question and is merely being used to serve as an example.

When I presented my design proposal to my team, they shot me down because the API was not "configurable" enough. They claimed that they did not want the API to make the link between "Phone number" and <Obscure Active Directory representation of Phone number>. Every person in the meeting (except for me) agreed that they would prefer to ask around, "What is the correct field in Active Directory to use for the user's phone number?", and plug that into their respective apps (LOL!).

They asked me, "What if our company decides to use a different field for phone number and you weren't around to make the change in *your* source code?" They eventually admitted that they were ***afraid*** to be tasked with changing someone else's source code, even if the code was pristine and had extensive unit tests. Every senior IT person in my department was in agreement on this.

Is this *really* the correct attitude to have when designing software?!

Comment: Are you saying that every business change would require a code-change? Your app is going to be hard-coded?

Comment: Considering the scope of this particular project and my company's history, a business change that would effect this app's code would occur about once per year.

Comment: Once a year is more than enough to warrant making a better application now.

Comment: James Jones, you mean "...that would affect this app's code..."?

Comment: @James: So you marked his as correct because he was the only one who agreed with you?

Comment: @devinb: Your answer is valuable (I did +1 you for it) and I am completely in agreement with you. Although your answer is relevant to "configuration", it does not pertain to the question as well as dsimcha. In fact, the design I proposed to my team was EASILY configurable and they still shot it down. The question is not about hard-coding vs configuration. It's about whether there is value in designing software such that is so flexible that it will never need to be updated. dsimcha was able to put a name on this concept and expanded my specific problem to a broader concept. That's why he wins.

Comment: You mentioned that "...they would prefer to ask around, "What is the correct field in Active Directory to use for the user's phone number?", and plug that into their respective apps".  Does this mean that it for example the phone number field changed, multiple apps using your API would have to be updated to send the correct field name in, instead of just your API?

Comment: YES! I even mentioned that exact scenario to them and they said "Well, James, if you're not here to make that change then we're screwed." I'm glad someone else is noticing the insanity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_platform_effect

While hard-coding too many assumptions into your program is bad, overzealously avoiding hard-coded assumptions can be just as bad.  If you try to make code excessively flexible, it becomes essentially impossible to configure, as the configuration scheme becomes almost a programming language in itself.  I think in general, phone number is a common enough thing that it can just be hard coded as a field.

Comment: Wow, the link and your description completely jives with what I'm trying to convey to my team. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If I understood correctly, they want to have the option of mapping the links outside the code, be it through a configuration file, a database, whatever. If that is correct, I think they have a valid point - why be forced to change any code at all if all you need to do is to change a configuration mapping.

Comment: They would prefer for there to be no mapping at all. They want it so flexible that they would not have to maintain any sort of mapping. The problem with a configuration file or a database is that they would detract from the distributed nature of the API.  Here's why: We have Active Directory nodes scattered throughout the globe. My API works off of the closest node. Unfortunately, we lack this sort of distributed nature in our databases and file servers, so pursuing this type of configuration would be less than ideal.

Comment: If there's no mapping at all, then what's the point of even having an API?  Just write something they can call to get a connection to the AD server.  BTW, anyone who doesn't want to "change someone else's source code" has obviously never done any maintenance programming, so is obviously living in a fool's paradise...

Answer (score 3):

If possible, you should *always* err on the side of more configurable. It will save you headaches later.

**Column Names**

Specifically in your case, columns in tables are an inherently *non-static* variable. They will commonly change as your needs change.

If you have a "**phonenum**" column, then they add a second phone number, they change the column to "**phonenum1**" and "**phonenum2**". It would need to be changed in the code. Then if they change them to "**Home_Phone**", "**Work_Phone**", "**Cell_Phone**" then the code would again have to be changed. If, however, you had a mapping file (a key/value config file) then all these changes would be extremely simple to make.

**In General**

I disagree with dsimcha that an application can be 'too configurable'. What he is talking about is 'feature bloat', where there are so many intertwining configurables that it becomes impossible to change any one without futzing all the others. This is a *very real problem*. However, the problem is not the number of configuring options, the problem is how they are presented to the user.

If you present all the configuration options in a concise, clear, streamlined manner. There should be comments to explain each one, and how it interacts with the others. In that case, you can have as many configuration variables as you want, because you have been careful to keep them segregated into singles or pairs, and have marked them as such.

You should be writing applications so that external (environmental) changes do NOT require code changes. Things such as

- Database user password changes
- Column names change
- "Temp folder" location changes
- Target Machine name/ip change
- App needs to be run twice a day instead of once
- Logging levels

None of those changes affect the *function* of the application and so there should be NO CODE CHANGES required. That is the metric you should use if you ever wonder whether hard-coding is all right.

If the **functionality** needs to change, it should be a code change. Otherwise, make it configurable.

Comment: I think you misunderstood dsimcha. Here is my interpretation of his answer: as my facade class becomes increasingly flexible, it becomes just as complex as the classes I'm trying to simplify, thereby increasing the overall complexity of the system.

Comment: @James Jones: No, I understood what he was saying. But it represents a misunderstanding 'configurability' vs 'modularity'. Configurability should mean that you have the option of changing VALUES in your code, not the functionality. If your 'configuration' options actually change the code (as dsimcha indicated) then you are putting modularity into your config, which is bad. Modules should be handled separately. In your case, because the column name is a value that could change, it should **100%** be in a config file.

Comment: I think there is some confusion with how the term "configurable" is being used. My team was suggesting that I make make the API more "configurable" in the sense that there would be no mapping to columns whatsoever - that they would reference the columns directly. I think I made this pretty clear in my question.

Comment: Right. They would like to keep control over what columns are used by referencing them directly. Part of the reason is because our Active Directory nodes are literally scattered all over the globe and we do not have a distributed file system to host the config file on. I agreed with them on this point. However, they also said that *even if* we had a DFS, a config file would not be desirable because it would require them having to locate it and edit it. THIS is what blew my mind.

Comment: It sounds to me like their arguments are strong. It would make the application MORE usable. The fact that if there WAS a config file, they STILL wouldn't edit it. That's fairly mindblowing, but in that case, I'd just write a stupidly-simple winforms app for "editing the config values" You could probably write than in under an hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying "should I hard code everything", then I think it's not a good idea.

In 2 years you will be gone and there will be a programmer that will waste a lot of time trying to update your legacy code when updating a configuration file would have been way easier.

In some cases it makes sense to hard code information, but I' don't think that your situation is one of these cases. I'd need more knowledge of the situation to be sure, this is just my guess from what you said.

Answer (score 1):

It seems easy enough to do both: produce a flexible API which allows the field to be specified, and then a wrapper around it which knows about the obscure ActiveDirectory name.

Of course, you *could* build that flexible solution later and just hard code the name for the moment. If that's significantly easier than the two-pronged approach, it's reasonable to argue for it - but if you'd probably end up with that sort of separation internally anyway, then it doesn't do much harm to expose it.

Answer (score 1):

I can honestly say I have been in your position before and I agree with the argument they are presenting you. Especially with an in-house app you will see feature creep. The more useful your application, the worse the feature creep. It is possible your application could be used in another office and they will have fields mapped differently than your current office. If you hard code mappings you are then stuck with different versions for different locations. Maintaining separate versions of source code quickly becomes a nightmare for a programmer. If you design in configurability now and your application is forgotten you have lost very little, but if your application becomes a standard across the company you have saved yourself an immense amount of time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Fear of change, as well as fear of accountability for making a change, is not uncommon in IT software organizations. Often, the culture in the organization is what drives this attitude.

Having said that, in your specific example, you are describing an API that provides a facade on top of the ActiveDirectory service - one that appears to be intended to be used by different groups and/or projects in your organization.

In that particular scenario, it makes sense to make portions of your API support configurability, since you may ultimately find that the requirements for different projects or groups could be different, or change over time.

As a general practice, when I build code that involves a mapping of one programming interface to another and there are data mapping considerations involved, I try to make the mapping configurable. I've found that this helps both unit testing as well as dealing with evolving requirements or contradictory requirements from different consumers.

Comment: Thank you for picking out that I am using the facade pattern. I edited the post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on why the API is being created, and what problems you're aiming to solve.  If the aim of the API is to be a service that lives on a server somewhere and manages requests from different applications, then I think your approach is probably the way to go, with the addition of a database or config files to perhaps customize the LDAP paths of certain properties.

However, if the goal of the API is to simple be a set of classes that abstract away the details of accessing Active Directory, but not what properties are being accessed, then what your coworkers have specified is the way to go.

Either approach isn't necessarily right or wrong, so it ultimately depends on your overall reasons for creating the API in the first place.